# Under which conditions is $\langle Ax, x \rangle= \langle x, x \rangle \Rightarrow$ A identity?

Tags: inner-products, advice

Under which conditions is $$\langle Ax, x\rangle = \langle x, x\rangle \implies A \text{ is the identity}?$$

I ask because I'd like to show that Isometry on a Hilbert space (Norm preserving) implies Adjoint is a left inverse or in formula $$\|Tx\|= \|x\| \implies \langle T^*Tx, x\rangle = \langle x, x\rangle \implies T^*T = I.$$

Edit: I think I have a solution that is a little bit restrictive:

I need that $T^*T$ to be a compact operator.

$T^*T-I$ is self-adjoint and also compact. Then I can use $||T^*T-I|| = \sup_{||x||=1} \langle T^*T-Ix, x \rangle $ and this supremum is attained since compact. So from this I conclude $||T^*T-I|| = 0 \Rightarrow T^*T-I = 0$ and we are done?

Comment: Shouldn't you be checking $\langle Ax, Ax\rangle=\langle x, x \rangle$? Meaning, you should be checking the norm of the same vector?

Comment: Makes no difference whether I look at $ \langle Ax, Ax \rangle = \langle A^*Ax, x\rangle$

Comment: I agree, but your first statement does not say that @Taleofwoe

Comment: @JacobA They have $A=T^*T$ here, as far as I can tell. They want to show from $\langle T^*Tx,x\rangle=\langle x,x\rangle$ that $T^*T=I$, so they wonder what operators allow for that conclusion, and whether $T^*T$ is such an operator. At least, that's how I read the question.

Comment: Ah I see the confusion, but Arthur is explaining exactly what I meant

Comment: Ahh I see, my apologies! Understood now

Comment: At least for finite dimensional spaces $\langle Ax, x\rangle =\langle x, x\rangle$ implies $A=I+D$, where $I$ is the identity and $D$ is an anti-symmetric matrix.

Comment: It means, $A=T^*T$ (which means $A$ is symmetric) leads to $A=I$. Since I need an ONB for my proof, I can only show it for finite dimensions.

Comment: Does your proof work, if we consider Hilbert spaces, since there we will get ONB?

Comment: The quadratic form $x\mapsto \langle Ax,x\rangle $ determines the operator $A,$ provided that it is a complex Hilbert space.